# Debian system - Network security tools

Tags: debian, networking

I am using Debian 6 and i need the best GUI/CLI tools which can  port,IP scanning and stalking of I/O data though the network .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [nmap](http://nmap.org/) for scanning ports, [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) to view usage statistics (for your own machine's interfaces), and [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to view all network traffic (that reaches your machine).

Comment: sometimes i need to hide my IP from other system ping . how can i do that ?

Comment: @raja.genupula: Use firewalling. Iptables. Maybe shorewall or similar.

Comment: any user guides for basic users please ? GUI tools ?

Comment: @raja.genupula: I would not recommend GUIs in general. If we are still talking about firewalls, you can try doing `apt-cache search firewall` and take a look at the results. fwbuilder has a gui, but I've never used it. You can also search on the tag `security::firewall`.